# Please help reword my OS upgrade question such that it can be reopened

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've attempted to reword [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109443/) several times to make it on-topic, but the moderators keep rejecting my flags for re-opening.    Please help me re-word the question such that it is on-topic.

On most StackExchange sites that I've used, I can tweak my question to fit within the guidelines.   I'm not sure why that isn't the case here so far.

The question is currently closed with the reason:

> "Questions asking us to find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or off-site resource are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly. [Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping)."

The question as it currently stands does not violate this rule and yet the moderators won't re-open it.   I've looked over [on-topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help center, but I can't identify a reason that wouldn't fit on the site as it is currently written.

So far, I have tried the following question titles:

- How do I choose an Android device on which I can upgrade the OS?
- How should I keep my Andoid phone always updated to the latest version of the OS?
- Do devices manufactured by Google get more OS upgrades than devices from other manufacturers?

Please help me word the question in such a way that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 3):

The more appropriate close reason for the current and previous revision of the post might be "primarily opinion based".

You could argue that one could collect statistics about which manufacturers upgrade the most often, and so on, but it's a rather complicated endeavor.  Within specific time periods and device lines you're going to find wildly different information, and none of it is useful going forward because there are simply no set-in-stone policies here.  We want questions to be useful to future readers without their answers needing to be revised all the time.

Ultimately it still seems like a shopping advice question, or at least suffers from the same issues as those questions.

I can't comment on the views of the other mods, but upon logging in today I found that all of them had viewed your post and declined to take action which is why I dismissed your flag.

Comment: I agree with Matthew here. I'd even go so far as declaring it an "Android independent device question" – and yes, a shopping recommendation. So in the review queue I'd decide to "keep it closed", it is not really within the scope of our site as I understand it. Still, I left you a comment there which hopefully proves helpful.